# Light point power keyframes not showing up in graph editor

Tags: keyframes, graph-editor, fcurves

Title is self explanatory. Trying to simulate flickering light via light power keyframes but there are no points in the graph editor even though i can see them in the dopesheet, timeline etc. For reference, I placed one keyframe on first frame in animation and one at the end and wanted to apply a noise F-Curve modifier to the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

In my particular case I could not see the points in the graph editor because the power of my light was 2000 W and it was way beyond the default view range.

As suggested by AtomicBezierSlinger you could perform a `Select All` (<kbd>A</kbd>) and then `View Selected` (<kbd>Numpad .</kbd>(the period key)):

[image: Zooming into the selected keyframes in the graph editor via the menu]

---

Alternatively, you could also `View All` (<kbd>Home</kbd>). This is convenient if a numerical keypad is not available.

Comment: You can press A to select all points or select the graph name. You can press the numeric keypad . that is a period.  This will bring graph points into view.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I wasn't aware of the numeric keypad shortcut since my laptop keyboard does not have a numeric keypad. I tried the period key with an on-screen keyboard and found the auto zoom-in seems to only work in the Shading panel --- is this the case?

Comment: Laptops can emulate numeric keyboard perhaps.  Someone might want to obtain an external keypad for you.  External keyboards can be attached to your laptop.  You may investigate user preferences.  Used keyboards are so common that they have become cheap in certain areas.  Select a few points on a graph and test with the (.).  I am no expert. I just thought you might want to add that to your answer.

Comment: My desktop space is constrained. I do not want to use an external keyboard that has a numeric keypad. I can tolerate and would like to know other methods that accomplish the functionalities of a numeric keypad. As I said, I had used the on-screen keyboard for that purpose. Keyboards being readily available is one thing, physically and mental clutter is also something that might worth considering. I do not use Blender for a living; it's a hobby for the time being.
Sounds good, I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: We have different version of Blender.  Menu item names are different.  Functionality the same.

Comment: I see, I'll take another look (I'm using 2.82a.)